# Different data value response for blpapi and bloomberg Excel Add-in

Tags: java, excel, bloomberg, blpapi

I have encountered a situation where in the data from Bloomberg Excel Add-in and blpapi are not the same.

The formula I use in Bloomberg excel is,

`=BDH("2902 HK Equity", "EQY_SH_OUT", "20160906", "20160906")`

It gives me, `472.014` as a result.

However, if I try to do this in blpapi, the value I get is different.
Below is the detail of my request.
`Ticker: 2902 HK Equity Start/End Date: 20160906 Fields: EQY_SH_OUT`

Below is the response

```
HistoricalDataResponse (choice) = {
    securityData = {
        security = 2902 HK Equity
        sequenceNumber = 0
        fieldData[] = {
            fieldData = {
                date = 2016-09-06
                EQY_SH_OUT = 4720.138
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Is it a bug that I have to consult with Bloomberg? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a 1 for 10 split on the 7th of September 2016 (yesterday). I suspect that your terminal is set to adjust splits and Excel returns the adjusted number of shares whereas your call to API returns actual historical data.

Without more information about how you call the API it's hard to say, but playing with the various adjustment settings should solve your issue, in particular:

```
request.set("adjustmentSplit", true); //or false depending on what you want
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Initially, adjustmentSplit is set to false in my code. When I replaced it to set adjustmentSplit to true, the response value is now the same as the Bloomberg excel Add-in gives. Thank you @assylias